# STM32F0 UART not working

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I'm new in ST world. I'm trying to work with UART, so I wrote this code to initializate UART and to send "Hello". I'am using STM32F0 board.

```
#include "stm32f0xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_misc.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_usart.h"

#define UINT8               uint8_t
#define UINT32              uint32_t


#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE     256

typedef struct Buffer_st
{
   UINT8 size;
   UINT8 data[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
}Buffer_st;

Buffer_st receivedDataUART1;

void initUART1(UINT32 baudRate)
{
   NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
   GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
   USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;

   /* Enable the USART1 Interrupt */
   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART1_IRQn;
   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPriority = 0;
   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
   NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

   //UART init
   USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = baudRate;
   USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
   USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
   USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
   USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
   USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;

   /* Enable GPIO clock */
   RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

   /* Enable USART clock */
   RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART1, ENABLE);

   /* Connect PXx to USARTx_Tx */
   GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_1);

   /* Connect PXx to USARTx_Rx */
   GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_1);

   /* Configure USART Tx, Rx as alternate function push-pull */
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_10;
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

   /* USART configuration */
   USART_Init(USART1, &USART_InitStructure);

   /* Enable USART */
   USART_Cmd(USART1, ENABLE);
   USART_ITConfig(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);

   resetReceivedDataBufferUART1();
}

void resetReceivedDataBufferUART1(void)
{
   receivedDataUART1.size = 0;
   memset(receivedDataUART1.data, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
}

UINT8 sendDataUART1(Buffer_st buffer)
{
  UINT8 cpt;

  for (cpt = 0; cpt < buffer.size; cpt++)
  {
     USART_SendData(USART1, buffer.data[cpt]);

     //Loop until the end of transmission
     while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_IT_TXE) == RESET);
  }
}

void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
   if (USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE) != RESET)
   {
       receivedDataUART1.data[receivedDataUART1.size++] = USART_ReceiveData(USART1);
   }
}

int main(void)
{
   Buffer_st buffer = {6,"Hello"};

   initUART1(9600);
   sendDataUART1(buffer);

   while(1);
   return 0;
}
```

I'am using UART/USB connector. The problem is that I don't receive any thing in minicom. When debugging I found that progrom enter in infinite loop

```
 //Loop until the end of transmission
while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_IT_TXE) == RESET);
```

Comment: Often this would indicate the peripheral is not clocked.  Can you examine the uart flag register and decode the bits that are set, according to the programmer's manual?  Does your chip require clocking the apb2 itself, or the afio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up interrupt status flags with the flags used for synchronous polling. To send data you must first poll the `USART_FLAG_TXE` flag for the *transmit data register empty* status and then you can send your byte. The `USART_IT_TXE` flag is for interrupt use only.

So, to send a byte, do something like this:

```
while(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1,USART_FLAG_TXE)!=SET);
USART_SendData(USART1,myByte);
```

Please see the documentation for the `USARTx_ISR` register in [RM0091](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031936.pdf) for further information.

Answer (score -3):

You use a function like this

```
void USART_write(unsigned char *string){

    while(*string){
        // wait until data register is empty
        while( !(USART1->SR & 0x00000040) );
        USART_SendData(USART1,*string);
        *string++;
    }
}
```

This code is tested on STM3VLDiscovery. You must check register status for your chip,like  while( !(USART1->SR & 0x00000040) );

Comment: The code you've provided is for a different microcontroller. It's also mixing up direct register access with SPL functions, which is best avoided.